# Changing TabControl SelectedIndex when adding a new TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf, tabitem

I made a button to add a new TabItem in my TabControl. It works fine, but i would like the SelectedIndex to be on the new TabItem when i add a new one. 
The code of the

```
private void AddNewTabItem(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ...
        tabControl.Items.Add(tabItem);
        tabControl.SelectedIndex = tabControl.Items.Count - 1;
    }
```

But this doesnt work, because the new TabItem is created after all the function linked to my button click are executed. So, when i change the SelectedIndex, the new TabItem is not created yet.

I searched for a triggerEvent on the TabControl class, like "WhenItemsChange" but i found nothing.

Thanks for help, and sorry if this is not clear.

Comment: You can try to use `OnItemsChanged` method and set `IsSelected` to the newly added tab item

Comment: I dont fin this method, could you be more precise?

Comment: Do `tabControl` and `MainWindow.tc` reference the same TabControl? What about `tabControl.SelectedItem = ti;`?

Comment: Yes it refers to the same TabControl, i edited so it is more clear. 

`tabControl.SelectedItem = ti` doesnt work neither. Because of the same problem as before, the TabItem is not fully created until the function has ended.

Comment: For example, i tried to add 
`MainWindow.tc.SelectedItem = ti;`
in the `button.MouseLeftButtonUp` instead of `button.MouseLeftButtonDown` and it worked. But that's not what i want.

Comment: Nice, ItemContainerGenerator.ItemsChanged was exactly what i was looking for. Thank you very much.

Comment: Note that the ItemChanged handler would have to check if an item was added, but not removed or moved. You could possibly write the handler such that it detaches itself after execution. However, it's even a lot simpler, see the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may create TabItems that are selected by default.

In case `ti` is already a TabItem, just write

```
ti.IsSelected = true;
tabControl.Items.Add(ti);
```

If not, assign an appropriate Style to the TabControl's `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabControl">
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: How to do it from code behind? 
I think it is easier to add an event handler to ItemsChanged

Comment: If `ti` is already a TabItem, it is even more simple. See the edit.

Comment: It doesnt work, there is still the problem that ti is not fully created when you set the IsSelected propert

Comment: You forgot to tell what `ti` actually is, a TabItem or not?

Comment: Yes, it is a tabItem

Comment: Then I fail to understand what "*not fully created*" is supposed to mean. The above works fine for me when I just add TabItems.

Comment: On my app, i have to click on a button to create a new TabItem. The code which creates a new TabItem is executed inside a eventHandler which is added to the button (is it clear?). 
So, the TabItem is not added to the TabControll until the end of this function, i dont know why. Is it more clear?

Comment: No idea what's going on there. As said, just setting the new TabItem's IsSelected property before adding it to the Items collection works fine for me - in a simple test application. Do not also set SelectedIndex or SelectedItem.

Comment: I dont know neither. For example, the following code doesnt work. 
`Image addTabItemButton = new Image();
addTabItemButton.MouseLeftButtonDown += AddNewTabItemFunction;
        
private void AddNewTabItemFunction(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
        TabItem tabItem = new TabItem();
        tabItem.IsSelected = true; 
        tabControl.Items.Add(tabItem);
 }`

Comment: Anyway, you should consider having XAML for the TabControl and the TabItem Style. Instead of creating UI elements in code behind, write a DataTemplate with elements that are bound to the properties of a data item class. Then add those data items to the Items collection, or even better, assign or bind the ItemsSource property to an ObservableCollection of data items.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
private void AddNewTabItem(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    tabControl.Items.Add(ti);
    Dispatcher?.BeginInvoke((Action)(
            () => tabControl.SelectedIndex = tabControl.Items.Count - 1));
}
```

Comment: This would only work by coincidence, because even after delayed execution the item container generation might not be completed.